# VSCode Color picker/Color box not working for CSS files - SPECIFICALLY CSS COLOR NAMES

Tags: css, colors, frontend, background-color, web-frontend

One day my color picker/color box stopped popping up once clicking/hovering for CSS files only. Works fine with HTML. I finally was able to get rgb, rgba, hex, hsl to work but for the life of me I cannot get the color names to work. Just say I write all my CSS color with only CSS color names it will render on the page but NOT in my VSCode. Im totally stuck.

I reinstalled vscode
Deleted json settings
Deleted extensions
Changed my theme
I manually went through and reset all my settings to default

How I was able to get other color formats to work was checking "Default Color Decorators"

I want the color picker and color box to pop up with click and hover in my CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to "Execute command VS Color Picker in Command Palette(Ctrl + Shift + P or Cmd + Shift + P)." as per the official docs. If this doesn't work type "color decorators" and make sure the **Editor: Color Decorators** setting is enabled, or you can install a free extension that can help you with the color picker thing.